# More efficient way of setting item in a numpy array (in place)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, in-place

I'm looking for the most efficient (=fastest) way of changing an item's value in a numpy array. Assumming I have an array `a = np.zeros((N,N))`, and I want to set a value at `i,i` to `x`, I have found following option: `np.itemset((i,i), x)` - this one seems fast, but it is not inplace. There is also `numpy.put`, but it seems to be slow... Are there any other options?

Comment: What's the bigger picture?  Why worry about the speed of a single, simple operation like this?  What's wrong with `x[i,j]=3`?

Comment: `itemset` docs says it's faster than the indexed notation, but it is discouraged because it obscures the code.  I have never used it or seen it used before.

Comment: `x.itemset(...)` operates in-place.  But in simple time tests, it isn't faster than `x[...]=...`.  Again, why are you worried about this?

Comment: https://pytech-solution.blogspot.com/2018/02/fast-pixel-processing-with-opencv-and.html I have written a blog and a comparison of using itemset and index based operatoion, Please check the link